# Automapper - how to map to constructor parameters instead of property setters

Tags: constructor, automapper

In cases where my destination setters are private, I might want to map to the object using the destination object's constructor. How would you do this using Automapper?

Answer (score 175, accepted):

Use `ConstructUsing`

this will allow you to specify which constructor to use during the mapping. but then all of the other properties will be automatically mapped according to the conventions.

Also note that this is different from `ConvertUsing` in that convert using will not continue to map via the conventions, it will instead give you full control of the mapping.

```cs
Mapper.CreateMap<ObjectFrom, ObjectTo>()
    .ConstructUsing(x => new ObjectTo(arg0, arg1, etc));
```

...

```cs
using AutoMapper;
using NUnit.Framework;

namespace UnitTests
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class Tester
    {
        [Test]
        public void Test_ConstructUsing()
        {
            Mapper.CreateMap<ObjectFrom, ObjectTo>()
                .ConstructUsing(x => new ObjectTo(x.Name));

            var from = new ObjectFrom { Name = "Jon", Age = 25 };

            ObjectTo to = Mapper.Map<ObjectFrom, ObjectTo>(from);

            Assert.That(to.Name, Is.EqualTo(from.Name));
            Assert.That(to.Age, Is.EqualTo(from.Age));
        }
    }

    public class ObjectFrom
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
    }

    public class ObjectTo
    {
        private readonly string _name;

        public ObjectTo(string name)
        {
            _name = name;
        }

        public string Name
        {
            get { return _name; }
        }

        public int Age { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm guessing "ConstructUsing" must be in a newer version of automapper than the one we're using. Thanks Jon

Comment: Much thanks for this example Jon.  "ConstructUsing" is great!  Allows me to keep my DTOs immutable with setters marked as private.

Comment: Works a treat for me; AutoMapper currently doesn't like constructors where all parameters are optional, so I just use .ConstructUsing(x => new MyClass());

Comment: How to do it with non-generic CreateMap method?

Comment: Tried something similar Mapper.CreateMap<Order, OrderViewModel>().ConstructUsing(x => new OrderViewModel(this));  ... Get a "The call is ambiguos" compiler error

Comment: @ChrisKlepeis it's giving you that error because it doesn't know what "this" is referring to when attempting to map between the types. you want to do .ConstructUsing(x => new OrderViewModel(x)) most likely.

Comment: Both methods throw "Expression must be writeable Parameter name: left" if you use readonly fields instead of a private setters on your destination object.

Comment: What if I needed to pass something more sophisticated than a `string`? What if `ObjectFrom` contained `ChildObjectFrom` type property which had to be passed to `ObjectTo` constructor?

Comment: Is this a better answer than @Matthieu's answer?

Comment: For anyone using this with EF Core - this worked in 2.2, but not in 3.0 due to a bug.  If you are on 3.0 you will need to upgrade to 3.1.1 to get the fix - https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/18888

Comment: You meant probably that all other **public** properties not present in the constructor will be mapped according to convention. Private properties will not be mapped, so `ConstructUsing` can successfully be used with aggregates. Am I right?

Answer (score 17):

The best practice is to use documented approaches from AutoMapper
http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Construction.html

```cs
public class SourceDto
{
        public SourceDto(int valueParamSomeOtherName)
        {
            Value = valueParamSomeOtherName;
        }

        public int Value { get; }
}

Mapper.Initialize(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<Source, SourceDto>()
  .ForCtorParam(
    "valueParamSomeOtherName", 
    opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Value)
  )
);
```

Comment: Unfortunately there’s no way to use `nameof` here to avoid brittle hard-coded magic-strings, and (unless AutoMapper now has a custom Roslyn rule) you won’t get a compile-time error if you omit a parameter or specify a parameter that doesn’t exist.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand the situation, but I use `nameof` with my `ForCtorParam` like this:

```csharp
CreateMap<Company, CompanyDto>()
    .ForCtorParam(nameof(CompanyDto.CountryCode), opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Country.Name));

CreateMap<OwnerCompany, OwnerCompanyDto>()
    .IncludeBase<Company, CompanyDto>()
    .ForCtorParam(nameof(CompanyDto.CountryCode), opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Country.Name));

Sorry about the formatting. I can't get formatting of code to work in comments any more

Answer (score 13):

You should use the `Map` method that lets you set the destination. For example :

```cs
Mapper.CreateMap<ObjectFrom, ObjectTo>()

var from = new ObjectFrom { Name = "Jon", Age = 25 };

var to = Mapper.Map(from, new ObjectTo(param1));
```

Answer (score 7):

At the time of writing this answer, AutoMapper will do this automatically (with a simple `CreateMap<>()` call) for you if the properties match the constructor parameters. Of course, if things don't match up, then using `.ConstructUsing(...)` is the way to go.

```cs
public class PersonViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Person
{
    public Person (int id, string name)
    {
        Id = id;
        Name = name;
    }

    public int Id { get; }

    public string Name { get; }
}

public class PersonProfile : Profile
{
    public PersonProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<PersonViewModel, Person>();
    }
}
```

Note: This assumes you are using [Profiles](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Configuration#profile-instances) to setup your automapper mappings.

When used like below, this produces the correct object:

```cs
var model = new PersonViewModel
{
    Id = 1
    Name = "John Smith"
}

// will correctly call the (id, name) constructor of Person
_mapper.Map<Person>(model);
```

You can read more about automapper construction in the offical [wiki on GitHub](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Construction)

Comment: Looks like CreateMap<> should be PersonViewModel and not PersonProfile. As well as in the second code block PersonModel should be PersonViewModel.

Answer (score 5):

Personally I always prefer to be as explicit as possible when using AutoMapper to avoid any potential bugs in the future.

If you call the `ConstructUsing` method just passing the parameters one by one in the good order you might face a bug one day.

What if a developer inverts 2 string parameters or add a new optional parameter before some existing optional parameters? You would get a mapping bug where a property isn't mapped to the destination property it's supposed to.
For that reason I prefer to define my mapping using named parameters when instanciating my object.

Here are the different signatures of the `ConstructUsing` method:

```cs
TMappingExpression ConstructUsing(Func<TSource, ResolutionContext, TDestination> ctor);
TMappingExpression ConstructUsing(Expression<Func<TSource, TDestination>> ctor);
```

In that case we want to use the first one because it's not possible to use named parameters in an Expression Tree (you would get a compilation error `an expression tree may not contain a named argument specification`).

Here is how to use it:

```cs
 CreateMap<FromType, ToType>()
    .ConstructUsing((src, res) =>
    {
        return new ToType(
            foo: src.MyFoo,
            bar: res.Mapper.Map<BarModel>(src.MyBar),
        );
    });
```

Note the Func's 2nd parameter `res` which is the `Resolution Context`. This parameter allows you to use already registered mappings.

Careful though, I'd like to catch your attention on a drawback of declaring mappings with constructors. If your classes don't have public setters (read-only properties or `private set`) you won't be able to use the following overload of the `Map` method:

```cs
TDestination Map<TSource, TDestination>(TSource source, TDestination destination);
```

This overload could be very handy when updating an entity with EF Core for example

```cs
mapper.Map(updateModel, existingEntity);
await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Thankfully there's [another way to update entities with EF Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/disconnected-entities#saving-single-entities).

Comment: Reg "What if a developer inverts 2 string parameters" I have the understanding that the names of the parameter matters, not the order.

Comment: Things I learned today: Having a mapper inside the `ConstructUsing`.