# AutoMapper public constructors

Tags: c#, automapper

Is there a way to override the need for a public constructor for the mapping to work?  Our objects are part of an API, and the base constructor requires that the record id be given.

Comment: It requires ID to be passed. May i know why you want to avoid that behavior

Comment: It is part of a piece that stops consumers of the API from changing the entity record id directly.

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2239143/automapper-how-to-map-to-constructor-parameters-instead-of-property-setters

Comment: So where would the ID come from instead? Is it already on an existing object?

Comment: @Jonas H: That was what i was looking for.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2239143/automapper-how-to-map-to-constructor-parameters-instead-of-property-setters

Comment: This post reference from @Jonas H gave me what i needed.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2239143/automapper-how-to-map-to-constructor-parameters-instead-of-property-setters