# How to use Automapper to construct object without default constructor

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

My objects don't have a default constructor, they all require a signature of

```
new Entity(int recordid);
```

I added the following line:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<EntityDTO, Entity>().ConvertUsing(s => new Entity(s.RecordId));
```

This fixes the problem where Automapper is expecting a default constructor, however the only element that is mapped is the record id.

How do I get it to pick up on it's normal mapping? How to get all the properties of the entities to be mapped without having to manually map the properties?

Comment: Where does RecordId come from? The EntityDTO? If so, the latest version of AutoMapper found at AutoMapper.org supports mapping constructor arguments, which might help you here.

Comment: You need to use ConstructUsing.
Look at [this answer][1] for details


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2239143/automapper-how-to-map-to-constructor-parameters-instead-of-property-setters

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You could use `ConstructUsing` instead of `ConvertUsing`. Here's a demo:

```
using System;
using AutoMapper;

public class Source
{
    public int RecordId { get; set; }
    public string Foo { get; set; }
    public string Bar { get; set; }
}

public class Target
{
    public Target(int recordid)
    {
        RecordId = recordid;
    }

    public int RecordId { get; set; }
    public string Foo { get; set; }
    public string Bar { get; set; }
}


class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Mapper
            .CreateMap<Source, Target>()
            .ConstructUsing(source => new Target(source.RecordId));

        var src = new Source
        {
            RecordId = 5,
            Foo = "foo",
            Bar = "bar"
        };
        var dest = Mapper.Map<Source, Target>(src);
        Console.WriteLine(dest.RecordId);
        Console.WriteLine(dest.Foo);
        Console.WriteLine(dest.Bar);
    }
}
```

Comment: The ConvertUsing gives more flexibility when it comes to map from the viewmodel to model. Is there any way that I could use ConstructUsing with ConvertUsing? I would like to just map a few properties when mapping from viewModel to model with a constructor but when mapping from model to view model all properties should be mapped.

Comment: Is there a way to make it more generic? Usecase: Convert from parent to child and whatever fields doent exist in parent, pass them as null in child

Answer (score 8):

Try

```
Mapper.CreateMap<EntityDTO, Entity>().ConstructUsing(s => new Entity(s.RecordId));
```