# How do i map nested objects

Tags: automapper, automapper-5

```
public class SecurityAccess : IdentityUser    {
    public string LName { get; set; }
    public string FName { get; set; }
    public string MName { get; set; }
    public DateTime NameDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime DOB { get; set; }
    public string Spouse { get; set; }
    public string Comments { get; set; }
    public Address Address { get; set; }       
}

public class Address {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int OwnerId { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
    public Company Company { get; set; }
    public string Department { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Location{ get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string Zip { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string Salutation { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }         
}

public class Company {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }        
    public DateTime CompanyDate { get; set; }    
}

public class ContactRegisterViewModel {
        public byte Id { get; set; }
        public String FName { get; set; }
        public String LName { get; set; }
        public String CompanyName { get; set; }
        public String AddressesTitle { get; set; }
        public String AddressesLocation { get; set; }
        public String AddressesCity { get; set; }
        public String AddressesState { get; set; }
        public String AddressesZip { get; set; }
        public String AddressesCountry { get; set; }
        public String AddressesPhone { get; set; }
        public String AddressesEmail { get; set; }
}
```

I have the following mappings set in Automapper

```
CreateMap<ContactRegisterViewModel, SecurityAccess>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Address,
                       opts => opts.MapFrom(
                            src => new Address
                            {
                                Address1 = src.AddressesAddress1,
                                Title = src.AddressesTitle,
                                City = src.AddressesCity,
                                State = src.AddressesState,
                                Zip = src.AddressesState,
                                Country = src.AddressesCountry,
                                Email = src.AddressesEmail,
                                Phone = src.AddressesPhone,

                            })).ReverseMap();
```

I am trying to convert the ContactRegisterViewModel to SecurityAccess. The conversion partially works. I am able to get the relevant properties filled in SecurityAccess including the Address property field that is in  SecurityAccess model however I am struck trying to further map the ContactRegisterViewModel property CompanyName to the property in Address.Company.Name.

Any suggestions how i can map the entire object tree?.

Comment: any help, kinda a desperate for a solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So one possible solution would go something like this:

```cs
CreateMap<ContactRegisterViewModel, SecurityAccess>()
    .ForMember(d => d.Address, o => o.MapFrom(s => s));

CreateMap<ContactRegisterViewModel, Address>()
    .ForMember(d => d.Title, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.AddressesTitle))
    .ForMember(d => d.Company, o => o.MapFrom(s => s));

CreateMap<ContactRegisterViewModel, Company>()
    .ForMember(d => d.Name, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.CompanyName));
```

This should get the job done, although it's probably not the most elegant. Might be worth a shot looking into those `ConstructUsing` / `ConvertUsing` methods (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7222460/1791065)).

Comment: You are a lifesaver, thank you @AlexandruMarculescu that was perfect, worked like a charm!!

Comment: If i throw a little curve ball and make The Address in SecurityAccess 

    `public IEnumerable<Address> Addresses { get; set; }` 

and Company in Address table

    `public IEnumerable<Company> Companies{get; set;}` 

How will the mapping be done?