# AutoMapperMappingException when using ConstructUsingServiceLocator() in ASP.NET Core 2.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, automapper, asp.net-core-2.1

I'm using AutoMapper 7.0.1 and AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection 5.0.1 in my ASP.NET Core 2.1 web application.  When I map to a type that isn't configured with `ConstructUsingServiceLocator()`, the mapping works.  When I map to a type that is configured with `ConstructUsingServiceLocator()`, it throws the following:

```
AutoMapperMappingException: Cannot create an instance of type 
AutoMapperTest.Destination
AutoMapper.MappingOperationOptions<TSource, TDestination>.CreateInstance<T>() in MappingOperationOptions.cs, line 47
```

I'm following the latest guidance for using AutoMapper with ASP.NET Core given here: [How to pass a service from .net core di container to a new object created with automapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46502264/how-to-pass-a-service-from-net-core-di-container-to-a-new-object-created-with-a/46525835#46525835)

I've reproduced this with a minimal example in a brand new project.  Here's the relevant parts:

New project > APS.NET Core Web Application > Web Application

Install AutoMapper 7.0.1 and AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection 5.0.1 Nuget packages.

**Source:**

```
public class Source
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

**Destination:**

```
public class Destination
{
    private readonly IDestinationRepository _repo;

    public Destination(IDestinationRepository repo)
    {
        _repo = repo ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(repo));
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

**IDestinationRepository:**

```
public interface IDestinationRepository
{
}
```

**DestinationRepository:**

```
public class DestinationRepository : IDestinationRepository
{
}
```

**MappingProfile:**

```
public class MappingProfile : Profile
{
    public MappingProfile()
    {           
        CreateMap<Source, Destination>().ConstructUsingServiceLocator();
    }
}
```

**Startup.ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services):**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddScoped<IDestinationRepository, DestinationRepository>();

    services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
    {
        // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
        options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
        options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
    });

    services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);

    services.AddAutoMapper();
}
```

**IndexModel:**

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly IMapper _mapper;

    public IndexModel(IMapper mapper)
    {
        _mapper = mapper;
    }

    public void OnGet()
    {
        _mapper.ConfigurationProvider.AssertConfigurationIsValid();            // <- Succeeds
        var repo = _mapper.ServiceCtor.Invoke(typeof(IDestinationRepository)); // <- repo is non-null

        var source = new Source {Name = "Test"};
        var destination = _mapper.Map<Source, Destination>(source);            // <- Fails!!
    }
}
```

The above fails on the `_mapper.Map<Source, Destination>(source)` call with the exception listed above.  I've verified `MappingProfile` is getting loaded.

If I change the `Destination` ctor to be parameterless, it still fails.

However, if I remove `ConstructUsingServiceLocator()` from `MappingProfile` (with the empty `Destination` ctor), my mapping starts to work.

What am I doing wrong here?  Thanks for any help!

Comment: I'm guessing: Your Destination class is not registered in di and so it's not possible to let di create a new instance of Destination.

Comment: That's it! If I add `services.AddTransient<Destination, Destination>();` in my Startup config, the mapping starts working.  I didn't expect to have to do this - DI containers I've worked with in the past don't require explicit registration of concrete types, and I didn't realize that the ASP.NET Core container did.  In fact, after considering some of the limitations of the ASP.NET Core container (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30681477/why-would-one-use-a-third-party-di-container-over-the-built-in-asp-net-core-di-c/30682214#30682214), I'll probably switch to a third-party container.

Comment: @christoph-lütjen - Add your comment as an answer and I'll give you the credit for solving my problem.  Thanks!

Comment: glad it worked, thank's for your feedback

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `Destination` class is not registered in di container and so it's not possible to let di container create a new instance of class `Destination`.