# How to map to a destination with a complex type ctor parameter?

Tags: c#, automapper

`Project` (destination) has both public ctor with paramters and protected parameterless ctor.

```
public Project(String name, User initiator) {
    this.Name = name;
    this.Initiator = initiator;
    this.InitializedOn = DateTime.Now;
}

// meant only to support some EF-related operations
protected Project() {}
```

The map:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<CreateProjectModel, Project>().ForMember(
    dest => dest.Name,
    opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.ProjectName)
);
```

Consider the excerpt from `create` action:

```
var user = dbContext.Users.Find(someId);
// initialize model using protected ctor - that's the behavior by default
var model = Mapper.Map<Project>(project);    
// then initialize some additional properties

// or initialize model as it needs to be
// var model = new Project(project.ProjectName, user); 
// and populate everything by hand
```

Is it possible to use `new Project(project.ProjectName, user)` initialization and to map the rest source properties using `Automapper`?

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2239143/automapper-how-to-map-to-constructor-parameters-instead-of-property-setters

Comment: @Fung I've already seen this thread. And it differs from what I'm asking. parameter `i` of `ConstructUsing(i =>` doesn't contain properties of Project model.

Comment: Source and destination are of different types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the other constructor is based on multiple source types, you may have to invoke it explicitly and map ther remaining properties through AutoMapper:

```
CreateProjectModel project = ...

var model = new Project(project.ProjectName, user);
Mapper.Map(project, model);
```