# Replace Mapping with ConstructUsing

Tags: c#, automapper

I make a mapping using Automapper 3.2.1:

```
    Mapper.CreateMap<AvvisoPec, EsitiPostalizzazione>()
        .ForMember(dst => dst.IDAvviso, src => src.MapFrom(v => EstraiIdAvviso(v)))
        .ForMember(dst => dst.CodiceErrorePiattaforma, src => src.MapFrom(v => EstraiCodiceErrorePiattaforma(v.History)))
        .ForMember(dst => dst.DescrizioneErrorePiattaforma, src => src.MapFrom(v => EstraiDescrizioneErrorePiattaforma(v.History)))
        .ForMember(dst => dst.CodiceEsitoPostalizzazione, src => src.MapFrom(v => EstraiEsitoPostalizzazione(v.History)))
```

And this works good. now I want to remove parameterless construction in order to use a better encapsulation::

```
public EsitiPostalizzazione(int IDAvviso, int CodiceEsitoPostalizzazione, String CodiceErrorePiattaforma, String DescrizioneErrorePiattaforma)
{
    this.IDAvviso = IDAvviso;
    this.CodiceEsitoPostalizzazione = CodiceEsitoPostalizzazione;
    this.CodiceErrorePiattaforma = CodiceErrorePiattaforma;
    this.DescrizioneErrorePiattaforma = DescrizioneErrorePiattaforma;
}
```

so as far as I documented I should use the `ConstructUsing`after the `createMap()` but I don't know how to use it, can someone help me?
All the [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2239143/automapper-how-to-map-to-constructor-parameters-instead-of-property-setters) on the web will make something like:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<AvvisoPec, EsitiPostalizzazione>()
      .ConstructUsing(x => new EsitiPostalizzazione(x.IdAvviso, ...))
```

but I have nothing like `x.IDAvviso`

Comment: What did you try and what was the problem there?

Comment: All documentation and example that I found do something that I can't do. See the updated answer for details...

Answer (score 2):

The `x` in the `ConstructUsing` lambda should be your source type, which is `AvvisoPec`. So when you're using the `EsitiPostalizzazione` constructor you need to provide the values the way you were doing when using the `MapFrom` syntax.

Based on your code I would expect it to be:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<AvvisoPec, EsitiPostalizzazione>()
      .ConstructUsing(v => new EsitiPostalizzazione(EstraiIdAvviso(v),
            EstraiEsitoPostalizzazione(v.History),     
            EstraiCodiceErrorePiattaforma(v.History),
            EstraiDescrizioneErrorePiattaforma(v.History)));
```