# AutoMapper - set a destination property to null when source property is not available

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, automapper

I have the following two objects -

```cs
public class Customer
{
    public Customer(string userName, string email)
    {
        this.UserName = userName;
        this.Email = email;
    }

    public string UserName { get; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}

public class CustomerUpdate
{
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

I don't want to add a constructor in `Customer` to initialize `Email` only. Can I create a map from `CustomerUpdate` to `Customer` so that `UserName` is set to null?

(I'm using AutoMapper 9.0.0)

Comment: this article https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4987872/ignore-mapping-one-property-with-automapper may help you

Comment: @KrishnaMuppalla, Thanks, but doesn't work. It throws `Customer needs to have a constructor with 0 args or only optional args. (Parameter 'type')` and I didn't want to have a constructor with 0 args.

Comment: @BrightHammer, thanks for the idea. That actually might work for the purpose now.

Comment: @atiyar the answer i provided in the comments also required a parameterless constructor unfortunately. Check my answer below for a way that does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a map and explicitly state the constructor to use.

```
CreateMap<CustomerUpdate, Customer>()
.ConstructUsing(s => new Customer(null, s.Email))
```

For more details check this answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/2239647/7772646

Comment: Thanks, didn't know about `ConstructUsing`. You have a typo ;)