# I keep getting "needs to have a constructor with 0 args or only optional args. (Parameter 'type')"

Tags: c#, automapper, automapper-9

I am using version 9.  I am using a Profile based configuration. When I run the application the Mapper.Map<>() method throws the following exception:

> JobAssist.Services.ResumeBankMgmt.API.Application.ViewModels.ResumeBankViewModel needs to have a constructor with 0 args or only optional args. (Parameter 'type')

I don't know what is causing this.

Comment: Many things require a type to have a *default constructor*. For example. If you have a `new()` constraint on a generic type, that type must have a default constructor. That way, instances of your type can be created using `new` without any knowledge of what parameters are needed for the constructor expression.The fix is to create a default constructor for your type. Classes get default constructor automatically unless you define a non-default one. In that case it's up to you to decide if your type needs one

Comment: If this is because of DI Constructor injection, automapper has options for this

Comment: I have other classes that don't require it.  Do you know when it is required or what drives to need it?

Comment: Can you post your code for your configuration inside Profile?

Comment: @LeeSong I got it solved.  Why do you need it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Classic mapping works for mapping based on source members:
https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Construction.html

If you cannot change the class (in contracts for example) having constructors with parameters that are different from members, you can use `ConstructUsing`.

You can use it like this to specify arguments :

```
Mapper.CreateMap<ObjectFrom, ObjectTo>()
    .ConstructUsing(x => new ObjectTo(arg0, arg1, etc));
```

Check the full answer here: [Automapper - how to map to constructor parameters instead of property setters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2239143/automapper-how-to-map-to-constructor-parameters-instead-of-property-setters)

Comment: That's just wrong :) See https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Construction.html.

Comment: Oh okay, I missed this part. I update

Answer (score 13):

The issue was that I had one parameter that was not named exactly like my class property.  See I changed `categories` in constructor to `resumeCategories`.

Original code:

```
public class ResumeBankViewModel
{
    public List<ResumeCategoryViewModel> ResumeCategories { get; set; }
    
    public ResumeBankViewModel(int id, int jobSeekerID, List<ResumeViewModel> resumes, List<ResumeCategoryViewModel> categories)
}
```

new code:

```
public class ResumeBankViewModel
{
    public List<ResumeCategoryViewModel> ResumeCategories { get; set; }

    public ResumeBankViewModel(int id, int jobSeekerID, List<ResumeViewModel> resumes, List<ResumeCategoryViewModel> resumeCategories)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have access to the source code, and this isn't in a 3rd party assembly you're referencing...

Find the definition of the class `ResumeBankViewModel` (ViewModels\ResumeBankViewModel.cs is probably a good place to start.)

And add this line:

```
public ResumeBankViewModel(){ }
```

If there is a line like this:

```
private ResumeBankViewModel() /* { etc. } */
```

Or this:

```
internal ResumeBankViewModel() /* { etc. } */
```

You might change the `private`/`internal` to `public`.

You may also wish to look at the other public constructors that are already defined and pass some appropriate values to one of them:

```
public ResumeBankViewModel() : this(value1, value2, value3) { }
```

Or make it's parameters optional:

```
public ResumeBankViewModel(object arg1 = value1, object arg2 = value2, object arg3 = value3)
```

Any of these might lead to more issues that you will need to work through, but one of these is the bare minimum to clear this error.

Comment: I have other classes that don't require it.  Do you know when it is required or what drives to need it?

Answer (score 0):

I got the this error when using a "wrong" access modifier, i.e. `internal` instead of `public`, when mapping between two classes.